# LastPass empty error message when autofill credentials

Tags: passwords, google-chrome-extensions, lastpass, firefox-extensions

So, I'm using the LastPass extension in Firefox and Chrome and it worked fine at the beginning but now every time I want to save my typed login & password, I receive this empty error message box:

[image]

This happens in Chrome and Firefox.

Anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Have you checked Lastpass support or documentation?

Comment: Yes, the docs had an extensive chapter on bugs in their software but no solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm running into the same problem. I followed [LastPass's debugging instructions](https://lastpass.com/debug.php) and determined that the server is responding with an HTTP 429 status code, which means "Too Many Requests". I get the feeling it's just a temporary issue due to adding a whole bunch of my passwords into LastPass in a short time period. Hopefully this is the only problem you were running into too!

Edit: 12 hours later it was working fine again.